# Different between Critical Section Controller and Simple Controller in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Could you tell me the different between Critical Section Controller and Simple Controller in JMeter?

I don't understand about them clearly.

I created example but their results are same.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Simple Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Controller) does nothing but group the samplers below it

> lets you organize your Samplers and other Logic Controllers. Unlike other Logic Controllers, this **controller provides no functionality beyond that of a storage device**

While  [Critical Section Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller) used to block threads executing in parallel

> ensures that its children elements (samplers/controllers, etc.) will be executed by only one thread as a named **lock will be taken before executing children of controller.**

Note that it doesn't work on distributed testing

> Critical Section Controller takes locks only within one JVM, so if using Distributed testing ensure your use case does not rely on all threads of all JVMs blocking.

If you work with one thread you won't notice the difference between controllers

Comment: Do you have example of Critical Section Controller?

Comment: @SophieNguyen use if there is a problem running 2 requests at same time, for example if you write to file and want to avoid failures

Answer (score 0):

1. Simple Controller is just a container, you can put Samplers as a child of it. It doesn't do anything at all, the only valid use case is using it in combination with [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) and [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) when you want to avoid code duplication

   [image]
2. Critical Section Controller ensures that its children are executed by **only one thread at a time**, it can be used a a global [lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) to avoid [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) (for example concurrent writing to the same file by several threads or something like this)

Comment: Could you give me example of Critical Section Controller?